# backtracking to match html tag using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to figure out how to use Regex in PHP to backtrack and find a `</div>` tag preceding some specific html.

Here is the full HTML I want to look at including the closing tag I want to find and ultimately remove from the string:

```
</div>
        <div class="dHeading">Grades
```

It actually has a new line and spaces in between the 2 tags.  So I want to target that `</div>` tag and remove it from the string.  Any help would be appreciated.

I am using an online regex tester.  Here is what I have right now.

Regex:

```
/(</div>)([\w\W]*?)(<div)/
```

Comment: `regex` **cannot** be used to parse HTML.

Comment: Why is that? Wondering...

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Sorry, yes, added that in now.

Comment: Change it to `/<\/div>\s+(?=<div)/`

Comment: It's not that regex is _totally_ incapable of parsing HTML, it's just like trying to perform surgery with a katana... You won't get very far without a huge mess. It's just not expressive enough to eloquently handle the nuances of html.

Comment: If you want to remove the inner close and open of a div tag, this works `</div\s*>(?:(?!</div\s*>)[\S\s])*(<div(?!\w)(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+)>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect if this question is about parsing HTML document at all and regex is totally fine to deal with it:

```
preg_replace('~</div>\s+(?=<div)~', '', $content);
```

will do the job. You needed a positive lookahead and considering whitespaces in middle of closing and opening tags, precisely.

Comment: This looks promising, but it doesn't seem to be working: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/mUP

Comment: `h` in `dHeading` wasn't capital in your regex. Check this https://3v4l.org/BVkjl